# How to zip multiple uploaded file in Django before saving it to database?

Tags: django, file-upload, zip

I am trying to compress a folder before saving it to database/file storage system using Django. For this task I am using ZipFile library. Here is the code of view.py:

```
class BasicUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        file_list = file_information.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'fileupload_app/basic_upload/index.html',{'files':file_list})

    def post(self, request):
        zipfile = ZipFile('test.zip','w')
        if request.method == "POST":
            for upload_file in request.FILES.getlist('file'): ## index.html name
                zipfile.write(io.BytesIO(upload_file))
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                content = fs.save(upload_file.name,upload_file)
                data = {'name':fs.get_available_name(content), 'url':fs.url(content)}
            zipfile.close()
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'InMemoryUploadedFile'
```

Is there any solution for this problem? Since I may have to upload folder with large files, do I have to write a custom TemporaryFileUploadHandler for this purpose? I have recently started working with Django and it is quite new to me. Please help me with some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InMemoryUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/) is an object that contains more than just file you should open file and read it content ( InMemoryUploadedFile.file is the file)

```
InMemoryUploadedFile.open()
```

---

You should open file with open() and then read() it's content, also you should check if you have uploaded files correctly also you could use with syntax for both zip and file
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: I tried with `zipfile.write(upload_file.file)` to read the content of the memory file. It gives me this error: `TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.BytesIO`

Comment: I have also used `zipfile.writestr(upload_file.name,upload_file.read())`. It created a zip file only with the latest uploaded file (Since I have selected multiple files to be uploaded). And the file is also empty inside. I really do not understand what to do.

Comment: You should open file with open() and then read() it's content, also you should check if you have uploaded files correctly also you could use with syntax for both zip and file
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: downvoted for lack of example use with zipfile.